# Do I need to make embedded objects be key identifiable using Realm SwiftUI SDK?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

For example, I have three object classes in which workout data is stored. The highest one stores the total workout and within the object is a list of workouts (which itself is an embedded object) and then within the workout I have a list of sets (which is again an object). Do these embedded objects need to have a key to be looped over to display/ edit in swiftUI view?

So far I have added a primary key within the highest object and have not modified other objects, as i am looking for how to move forward with the object models.

Comment: *Do these embedded objects need to have a key* - No? In fact *Embedded objects cannot have primary keys or indexed properties*. Do you have some code you're stuck on? If so, post it, the description of the issue and troubleshooting. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Embedded objects in Realm are *conceptually* embedded, owned and destroyed by the parent object's lifetime in the Realm. They don't have indexes including a Primary Key.

However, if you're listing them in SwiftUI, you are correct that you need to provide an `id` for them. This only needs to be unique for the duration of this list, so you don't have to store it. If there's a unique property in the embedded object, just use that field. Otherwise you need an `id` adding. Please add more code to your question to make this easier to answer.

See [Working with Identifiable items in SwiftUI - HackingWithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/working-with-identifiable-items-in-swiftui)